# How to get HTML% select option value using JQuery

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I have HTML5 code:
    
                Select item:

And code behind:

```
function fillItemsList(jsonResponse){
    var data = jsonResponse.invocationResult;
    var itemsString  = data.commodities.toString();
    itemsList = itemsString.split(",");
    $('#selectItem').empty();
    var options = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < itemsList.length; i++) {
        WL.Logger.debug(itemsList[i]);
         options += '<option value= "' + itemsList[i] + '">' + itemsList[i] + '</option>';

    }
    $('#selectItem').html(options);
    busyIndicator.hide();
    //$('#selectItem').Attributes.Add("onChange", "return itemSelectionChange();");
}
function itemSelectionChange(){
    WL.Logger.debug("Selected item changed");
    var index = $('#itemsList').prop("selectedIndex");
    var selectedItem = itemsList[index];
    getDeals(selectedItem);

}
```

I am using IBM Worklight to create a web app and using this code. The select dropdown gets all the values but the function doesnt get invoked when the selection is changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

depends on what version of jQuery you are using, but the line:

```
//$('#selectItem').Attributes.Add("onChange", "return itemSelectionChange();")
```

should be something like:

```
$('#selectItem').bind('change', function(){return itemSelectionChange();});
```